# Spring Boot App -> Docker-compose.yml file containing Kafka cannot connect with each other as Kafka Producer and Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I try to implement an example of CQRS in Spring Boot. I have two main modules named as bank-account and cqrs-core. bank-account comprises 3 modules which are account-cmd, account-common and account-query.

Account-cmd is based on **command** process with **Kafka Producer** while account-query is based on **querying** with **Kafka Consumer**.

I created two **docker-compose.yml** files. One is for account-cmd and the another one is for account-query.

I run the docker-compose through this command shown below.

```
docker-compose --build
```

After running thems for each related modules, I see that all containers are up.

When I try to send any request through Postman like shown below

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/openBankAccount

{
    "accountHolder" : "Account Holder 1",
    "accountType" : "SAVINGS",
    "openingBalance" : 50.0
}
```

I always see this message `Sending request...` in the Postman.

Kafka Producer logs shown below (docker-compose.yml of account.cmd).
I only see this message constantly.

```
...
2023-03-24 21:09:12 2023-03-24T18:09:12.993Z  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
...
```

Kafka Consumer logs shown below (docker-compose.yml of account.query)
I only see this message constantly.

```
...
2023-03-24 21:10:05 2023-03-24T18:10:05.405Z  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-bankaccConsumer-4, groupId=bankaccConsumer] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
...
```

After waiting a certain amount of time, this message appeared on the console for account.cmd side.

```
org.springframework.kafka.kafkaexception : Send failed
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic AccountOpenedEvent not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml file shown below

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  account-cmd:
    image: 'account-cmd:latest'
    build:
      context: ./account.cmd
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      - kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      - spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
      - spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
      - spring.data.mongodb.database=bankAccount
      - server.port=5000
      - spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
    networks:
      - bankAccount

  account-query:
    image: 'account-query:latest'
    build:
      context: ./account.query
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - database
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/bankAccount?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - server.port=5001
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=bankaccConsumer
      - spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
      - spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      - spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      - spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*
      - spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
    networks:
      - bankAccount

  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ippavlova_1990
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ippavlova_1990
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - bankAccount
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10


  mongodb:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: mongo-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db
    networks:
      - bankAccount

  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - bankAccount

  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=CLIENT
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - bankAccount


volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
  db-data:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  bankAccount:
```

I get this issue from account-query (Consumer)

```
2023-03-26 02:04:27 2023-03-25T23:04:27.160Z  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-bankaccConsumer-3, groupId=bankaccConsumer] Request joining group due to: consumer pro-actively leaving the group
```

I get this issue from account-cmd (Producer)

```
2023-03-26 02:04:29 2023-03-25T23:04:29.086Z  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

I also added `KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`
and added a `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092` to **account-cmd**  **account-query** but nothing changed.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/cqrs-example)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you dont create the 'AccountOpenedEvent' topic in kafka. Make sure that the topic exists. If you want to create topic programmatically, you may try to do something like this

```
     @Bean
     public NewTopic topic() {
         return new NewTopic("AccountOpenedEvent", 2, (short) 2);
     }
```

s. also
https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/programmatically-create-kafka-topics-using-spring-kafka-8db5925ed2b1

UPDATE:
you can also try this setup of kafka service

```
kafka:
image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
ports:
  - '9092:9092'
  - '19092:19092'
environment:
  - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092, OUTSIDE://localhost:19092
  - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
  - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092, OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:19092
  - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
networks:
  - bankAccount
```